# How to pass environment variable in docker-compose command from the terminal

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

In docker we can pass environment variable as `docker run -e  -e "TEST_SUITE=TNT-TestSuite.xml".`

Can I do the same or similar for the docker-compose? Right now I had to define this kind envirment varible into the docker-compose.yml file. But I want to pass it when I run the command as `docker-compose -e "TEST_SUITE=TNT-TestSuite.xml" up` or something similar? Please let me know.

Comment: Like [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-with-docker-compose-run) ?

Comment: You can pass a value at runtime but you'd still need to define the variable in the env -> https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/
As for example in the environment section of the docker compose you should add the definition for TEST_SUITE=${TEST_SUITE} and then at runtime you can add the variable in the docker-compose run

Answer (score 3):

I am doing it in this way:

Docker-compose part:

```
  some-app:
    ...
    environment:
      - ENV_VAR_1=${ENV_VAR_1}
      - ENV_VAR_1=${ENV_VAR_2}
    command: some command
```

And then command:

```
ENV_VAR_1="value1" ENV_VAR_2="value2" docker-compose  -f ./docker/docker-compose.yml (path to docker-compose file) run some-app
```